# maven compiler in intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What is the point of using maven in intellij if it dose not work without setting the correct JDK under various intellij options?
What I mean is that now with intellij I have to set the JDK in 3 different places.

1. File->Setting->Build->Compiler
2. File->Project Structure->Project
3. File->Project Structure->Modules

While I aspect expect that when i compiler on the right side where are the maven options it works just by watching the pom file.

Answer (score 0):

i think that depends on what type of project you want to make but personally i find maven nice to use because you can set up several actions in the pom file (for example when compiling Less files, excluding them from the build and just using the resulting css files).

another feature would be the easy way to add dependency's from the maven rep http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: mvnrepository.com is not a maven repository it's only a search engine...